# HTTP PUT method implementation in C

Tags: c

I need to implement the HTTP PUT method in C using TCP socket.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at libcurl especially [the example for http put](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpput.html)

Or [libneon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/). PUT is in [ne_basic.c](http://svn.webdav.org/repos/projects/neon/trunk/src/ne_basic.c).